# Laravel - How to load a hasone relation on a hasmany relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to load a hasone relation on a loaded hasmany relation.

Basically, I have loaded my completion logs, but would like to also load the pool_section model relation for each of the loaded completion log records.

```
$appointments = Appointment::primaryAppointments()->ofReportingPeriod($reportingPeriod->id)->take(5)->get();

$appointments = $appointments->load('profile', 'department')->load(['completion_logs' => function ($query) use ($reportingPeriod) {
    $query->where('reporting_period_id', $reportingPeriod->id)->whereNotNull('pool_section_id')->orderBy('pool_section_id');
}]);
```

Trying to load the pool_section relation onto the loaded completion logs from above:

```
class PoolSectionCompletion extends Model

public function pool_section()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PoolSection', 'pool_section_id', 'id');
}

class Appointment extends Model

public function completion_logs()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\PoolSectionCompletion', 'App\Models\Profile', 'id', 'profile_id', 'profile_id', 'id');
}
```

I'm trying to load the select completion logs an then load the pool_section relation based on the id in order to get the pool_section data for each of the loaded completion logs. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

It seems if I add the relation as below -- it is mapping properly, but bringing in all the completion logs for each reporting period, not just the one defined per the route. I need the completion logs for the defined reporting period, but with the mapped hasone relation to the pool_section.

```
$appointments = $appointments->load('profile', 'department')->load(['completion_logs' => function ($query) use ($reportingPeriod) {
    $query->where('reporting_period_id', $reportingPeriod->id)->whereNotNull('pool_section_id')->orderBy('pool_section_id');
}])->load('completion_logs.pool_section');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It never fails... Spend days/hours trying to resolve and then finally post the question only to be able to resolve it a couple hours later after some addition effort.

I was able to achieve what I needed by simply loading the relationship onto the hasmany relationship.

```
class Appointment extends Model

public function completion_logs()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\PoolSectionCompletion', 'App\Models\Profile', 'id', 'profile_id', 'profile_id', 'id')->with('pool_section');
}
```